# Compile PHP extension in windows 7 for laragon environment

Tags: windows, php-7

I am currently stuck with a dev environment running windows 7 and laragon (https://laragon.org/) .
I would like to use the following extension for php 7.1 :
https://github.com/Megasaxon/php-xxhash

First, is this possible ? And second , how could I achieve this ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Paolo_Mulder: Here are my answers:
1. Yes, it is possible.
2. You can follow this great article to archive it:
http://blog.benoitblanchon.fr/build-php-extension-on-windows/

However, be aware that it's not a simple task :)

Comment: I guess it's important to you, so I've built one for you:
https://github.com/leokhoa/php-xxhash/releases/download/1.0.1/php_xxhash.dll